# cAdvisor is failing to collect the data for processes running inside the LXC container

Tags: docker, lxc, cadvisor, lxc-docker

I am using the cadvisor to collect the container health data.Here, I am using the below command to run the cadvisor:

> sudo docker run --volume=/:/rootfs:ro --volume=/var/run:/var/run:ro
> --volume=/sys:/sys:ro --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro --publish=8080:8080 --detach=true --name=cadvisor google/cadvisor:latest

I am getting the CPU and memory-related data but it is failing to collect the state of the process running inside the LXC container.

For example:
I want to get the state of the process "p", it is running inside the LXC container but the advisor is showing it as running.

`ps` output inside the container:

> ```
> sh-4.4# ps ax | grep Audio
> 105 ?        Ssl    0:00 Audio -d
> 364 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep Audio
> ```

But, in cadvisor dashboard it is not showing as running state. It is giving "0" for the process which is running inside the container:

> container_tasks_state{id="/lxc.payload.mycontainer/system.slice/Audio.service",image="",name="",state="running"}
> 0

Even it is not collecting any process-related data:

[image: usage and cpu]

Can anybody suggest to me what wrong I am doing here, please?

Regards.